# how to map column names to their shortnames

Tags: excel, vba

i have tried to copy and paste the columns with names like application id,number,address from an worksheet in workbook1 to another worksheet in workbook2 with column names in the order addr,appid,num (which are the shortnames of the columns in the first sheet).can anyone help how to map the column application id to appid,number to num and so on.The order in the second worksheet may differ.so indexing wont work here.this is the code i have tried,but the problem is it gets copied as it is like the first column in the source gets copied to the first column in the destination.what i want is to map the first column say "applicationid" to the column"appid"(this may not be the first column in destination) in the destination sheet..thanks in advance

```
     Dim thisWB As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
     Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
     Dim tmp
     On Error GoTo errorHandler
     Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
     tmp = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #1")
     If tmp = False Then Exit Sub  ' File not choosen'
     Workbooks.Open Filename:=tmp, ReadOnly:=True
     Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range to copy", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

   tmp = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #2")
   If tmp = False Then ' File not choosen'
   wb1.Close
   Exit Sub
   End If
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=tmp
   Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

   Set rng2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range where to paste", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

 rng1.Copy Destination:=rng2

  wb1.Close
  wb2.Close
  Exit Sub

'Error handler'
 errorHandler:
 MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. `columns with names` - is that the text in the first row of the column? What are `shortnames`? You can just copy and paste a worksheet from one workbook to another. What exactly is the problem? Are you using range names? Can you explain your scenario in more detail, with the proper terminology?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. This looks like a request for code which isn't what this site is about.

Comment: thank you for your replies..yes the column names are the data in the first row of the column.In the first sheet i have column names(the text in the first row) like applicationid,number and address and i want to map them to another worksheet with columnnames num,addr,appid..so i want data under applicationid to get pasted under appid....please help...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Function GetShortName(longName As String)
    Select Case longName
    Case "application id": GetShortName = "appid"
    Case "number": GetShortName = "num"
    Case "address": GetShortName = "addr"
    Case Else
        Err.Raise 9999, , "Unknown long name"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: thank you Jean-Francois for your reply...yeah i need something like this..i need to paste the cells under applicationid to the cells under appid..as i am a fresher can u please be a bit explanatory...thank you again